# How to exclude PDF folder from samba recycle?

Tags: samba, samba4

My problem is how can I exclude the folder PDF from recycle (/home/*/PDF)?
I have tested to exclude PDF;PDF/;/home/*/PDF... Nothing works.

```
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = no
    vfs objects = recycle
    recycle:keeptree = yes
    ....
    recycle:exclude_dir     = PDF/
```

Answer (score 0):

recycle:exclude_dir = /home/'user'/PDF/*

Comment: EDIT: (recycle:exclude_dir = /home/'user'/PDF/*) only works for directories in you PDF folder. (recycle:exclude_dir = /home/'user'/PDF) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

using `%S` (username) or using the name of the users, but

```
recycle:repository = /home/%S/.recycle
```

works 100%